# R - Data.table - Drop columns by reference using negative position

Tags: r, data.table

I like data table's way of deleting columns:

```
library(data.table)
data <- mtcars
setDT(data)
data[, 1:3 := NULL]
```

Deleting columns by position is not always the best solution, but it is often convenient. I expected this to work (delete all columns that are not in position 1:3):

```
data[, !1:3 := NULL]
```

But that returns this error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(data, , `:=`(!1:3, NULL)) : 
  LHS of := isn't column names ('character') or positions ('integer' or 'numeric')
```

Inspecting data in the same way does work:

```
data[, !1:3]
    hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
 1: 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
 2: 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
 3:  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
 4: 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
...
```

I can do something like:

```
delCol <- colnames(data)
delCol <- tail(delCol, -3)
data[, c(delCol) := NULL]
```

But it is less convenient. Is there a better way?

Comment: am i missing something. whats stopping you from doing ```data = data[, 1:3]``` ?

Comment: `!` is normally applied on logical vectors. 1:3 is not logical.

Comment: StupidWolf: You're right. I got so obsessed about deleting by reference that i ignored the most obvious answer. I still think it would be neat to drop with !1:3, though :-)

Comment: There is a pending PR that would allow for ```dt[, names(.SD) := NULL, .SDcols = !1:3]```. https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/4163 . Likewise, if you are only interested in selecting columns as opposed to deleting, you can do ```as.data.table(iris)[, !1:3, with = FALSE]```

Comment: I've been watching this PR for a while. Thanks for your work on this killer feature @Cole.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for sharing that @Cole

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, you can select just the first three columns, as suggested in comments. But if you really want to delete by reference, you might consider working with `colnames`:

```
library(data.table)
data <- mtcars
setDT(data)

data[, colnames(data)[-c(1:3)] := NULL]

head(data)
#>     mpg cyl disp
#> 1: 21.0   6  160
#> 2: 21.0   6  160
#> 3: 22.8   4  108
#> 4: 21.4   6  258
#> 5: 18.7   8  360
#> 6: 18.1   6  225
```

Alternatively, something like this would work:

```r
data[, setdiff(1:ncol(data), 1:3) := NULL]
```